# Prevent TinyMce in Joomla to modify inserted html code

Tags: joomla

I'm using joomla (last version) and just added this template in tinymce :

```
<a href="/test" class="darkimagediv">
    <img src="/images/logo2.png">

    <div>
        <div>
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

It displays fine in the popup dialog just before inserting, but when I do it is inserted like that:

```
<p><a class="darkimagediv" href="test"> <img src="images/logo2.png" /></a></p>
<div>
<div>Test</div>
</div>
<p> </p>
```

Which is very bad.
I'm superuser and text filtering is off in the global configuration. I don't find any cleanup option in tinymce, so I need to find which script modify my html but I don't even know if I must search tinymce or joomla itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pasting code **Don't use a rich text editor**.

The editor is doing what it is supposed to and correcting your incorrect markup. Either way, if you want to insert markup, incorrect or not, then don't use a rich text editor.

Comment: I don't think there's something incorrect in my code. Also the idea is to create code template for a customer so, he needs a rich text editor, not me.

Comment: You have an inline element which is not contained within a block-level element. As a text editor is designed for text the editor is correctly inserting the p elements as a container.